# Add user from PeopleSoft to User profile

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

E.g. we have SP 2010 application along with PeopleSoft application. Now we want to add users from PeopleSoft application to the User profile and merge with existing users with UPS database. What are the ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can write PowerShell script or Timer Job and execute it periodically.
In code you can read information from PeopleSoft for example. Then check if such user already has profile, just update it, if user hasn't create new user profile. Look at [this blog post](http://www.anmolrehan-sharepointconsultant.com/2011/09/create-user-profile-programmatically.html) for information how to create new user profile programmaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Forefront Identity Manager to merge the identities before importing them into SharePoint.

Comment: Dear Trevor,Do u mean Anton Kh's answer http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/74240/17251 is not correct?

Comment: Anton's answer is not incorrect, there are just multiple ways to approach the solution.  FIM is one of them, creating a custom timer job/using the UPA Web Service are just two other ways of accomplishing the same task.

Answer (score 0):

You need an LDAP source to create the profile. After that you could augment the profile from PeopleSoft through the BCS.

Comment: Technically you do not need an LDAP source as you can use any source to create an initial profile via custom development.